# How to structure Jinja2 templates when displaying two versions of the same object?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am building a website with Python/Flask/Jinja2 which involves user-created listings. Every listing has an expiration date, so every listing is therefore either active or expired.

Each listing will have its own page at `mysite.com/listings/<listing_id>`. An expired listing page will look different from an active listing page. The differences may be many, yet the high-level structure of the page will be the same (after all, both are listings on the same website).

What is the best way to structure the template and logic? I see two options:

First, I could create two Jinja2 templates: `listing.html` and `listing_expired.html`. The view function will figure out whether a listing is active or expired, and then render the appropriate template. A downside is that the two templates will have to be kept in sync.

Or, I could have just one template: `listing.html`. The template would then contain logic in it to test whether the listing is expired. One part of the template would be used if it's expired, and another if it is not (using a big `if-else` statement).

What is the right way to structure this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jinja template inheritance for this. Using generalisation you create a base template and extend this template with two child templates (listing and expired) and child blocks to create your views. Conclusion : three templates without a big if-else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to have two different templates and inherit the high-level structure by both of them.